# unable to add data to the database with asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I can't add my data to the database !!!
My code is correct and I don't have any errors or warnings !
I tried the same code with another model and another controller and it worked but with this model and controller it doesn't work !!!!
I'm about to lose my mind :(

This is my view code :

```html
@model mvc_depences.Models.Projet
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/admin.cshtml";
}
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <fieldset>
        <br />
        <legend class="legend">Ajouter Un Nouveau Projet</legend>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <br />
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <label class="cke_label" for="NomP">Nom</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom Projet" data-val="true" required="" data-val-length="Taille max  est 50 caracteres !! " data-val-length-max="50" id="nom" name="nom">
                                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="nom" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br /><br />
                        <!--Date Debut !!-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <label class="cke_label" for="DateDebut">Date Debut</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header text" style="width: 245px;">
                                    <span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
                                        <input data-val="true" class="text k-input" style="width: 100%;" data-val-date="The field DateDebut must be a date." data-val-required="Le champ DateDebut est requis." id="DateDebut" name="DateDebut" type="text" data-role="datepicker" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="DateDebut_dateview" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
                                        <span unselectable="on" class="k-select" role="button" aria-controls="DateDebut_dateview">
                                            <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-calendar">select</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                                <script>
                                    jQuery(function () {
                                        jQuery("#DateDebut").kendoDatePicker({ "format": "yyyy-MM-dd", "min": new Date(1950, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), "max": new Date(2000, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0) });
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <span class="text" data-valmsg-for="DateDebut" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br /><br />
                        <!--Date fin Prevue !!-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <label class="cke_label" for="DateFinPrevue">Date Fin Prevue</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header text" style="width: 245px;">
                                    <span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
                                        <input data-val="true" class="text k-input" style="width: 100%;" data-val-date="The field DateFinPrevue must be a date." data-val-required="Le champ DateFinPrevue est requis." id="DateFinPrevue" name="DateFinPrevue" type="text" data-role="datepicker" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="DateFinPrevue_dateview" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
                                        <span unselectable="on" class="k-select" role="button" aria-controls="DateFinPrevue_dateview">
                                            <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-calendar">select</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                                <script>
                                    jQuery(function () {
                                        jQuery("#DateFinPrevue").kendoDatePicker({ "format": "yyyy-MM-dd", "min": new Date(1950, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), "max": new Date(2000, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0) });
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <span class="text" data-valmsg-for="DateFinPrevue" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br /><br />
                        <!--Date fin Reele !!-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <label class="cke_label" for="DateFinReele">Date Fin Reele</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header text" style="width: 245px;">
                                    <span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
                                        <input data-val="true" class="text k-input" style="width: 100%;" data-val-date="The field DateFinReele must be a date." data-val-required="Le champ DateFinReele est requis." id="DateFinReele" name="DateFinReele" type="text" data-role="datepicker" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="DateFinReele_dateview" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
                                        <span unselectable="on" class="k-select" role="button" aria-controls="DateFinReele_dateview">
                                            <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-calendar">select</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                                <script>
                                    jQuery(function () {
                                        jQuery("#DateFinReele").kendoDatePicker({ "format": "yyyy-MM-dd", "min": new Date(1950, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), "max": new Date(2000, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0) });
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <span class="text" data-valmsg-for="DateFinReele" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br /><br />
                        @*<div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="cke_label" for="Description">Description</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <textarea rows="6" cols="40"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>*@
                        <br /><br />
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <label class="cke_label" for="etat">Etat</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div align="justify">
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="group2" value="En_Cours" checked> En Cours<br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Termine"> Terminé<br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Annule"> Annulé<br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" style="margin-left:400px;margin-top:120px">
                            <div class="col-md-12" style="width:350px">
                                <input id="Submit" class="btn btn-default" name="actionType" type="submit" value="Engeristrer" style="width:150px" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

My controller code :

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using mvc_depences.Models;

namespace mvc_depences.Controllers
{
    public class ProjetController : Controller
    {
        private BD_GestionDepences db = new BD_GestionDepences();
        public ActionResult CreateProjet()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult CreateProjet([Bind(Include = "idProjet,nomP,DateDebut,DateFinPrevue,DateFinReele,etat")] Projet projet)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Projets.Add(projet);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(projet);
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the controller is called when page is submit?

Comment: When your view gets rendered, what is the form action that you see in the source?

Comment: Do you hit a breakpoint inside `if (ModelState.IsValid)`?

Comment: @SmitPatel how can i khow ? all what i know is when i go to the controller and click go to view it move me to the view and the same thing with the view -> controller

Comment: @elolos i didn't understand you

Comment: @BrunoLM no ! i didn't

Comment: Put the debugger, When your page is submit then on the Post method to see the method is calling or not.

Comment: @kokomoi when the page with the form is loaded and you view its source code, what is the action attribute in `<form action="/someUrl">`?

Comment: Put a breakpoint there and check which errors are in the model. You probably have some required field that is not being sent.

Comment: @BrunoLM i've added it and it didn't work

Comment: So you put a break point on 'if (ModelState.IsValid)' and it is showing valid and proceeding to the database update portion? Next step is to wrap the update in a try/catch: http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/c1bff938-1789-4501-8161-3f38bc465a8b.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Change this line as this and try again,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateProjet","Projet",FormMethod.Post))
```

> EDITED - Try this by removing Bind may be this will work

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateProjet(Projet projet)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Projets.Add(projet);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(projet);
}
```

**This may not possible but still check the connection string, that it's affecting the same DB or another.**

Comment: Why would you need to do this - all those values are the defaults - its completely unnecessary.